# TinyMCE image uploading overriding images_upload_handler

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, tinymce, image-uploading

I've got TinyMCE and drag-and-drop image uploading working well. I've specified `images_upload_url: 'handler.php'` and have written the handler which receives the data and handles it appropriately.

However there is one single extra parameter I would like to dynamically pass up to the handler.php from the client side at the time an image is dropped onto the page.

I see in the documentation that you can "roll your own" function by writing your own images_upload_handler function. That would suffice, however I'd rather use the existing TinyMCE one for simplicity. I was wondering is there a way I can somehow dynamically change the images_upload_url to dynamically append a GET parameter (eg ?foo=bar) just before the default images_upload_handler function runs? Or is there a way I could specify my own function for images_upload_handler, but then call the default 'parent' TinyMCE function straight after? I'm thinking something like this (just as a mockup/idea):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    images_upload_url: 'handler.php',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        // change images_upload_url to handler.php?foo=bar
        // call default TinyMCE images_upload_handler function. 
    }
})
```

Or alternatively, rather than overriding the images_upload_handler directly, is there a function or event I can hook into after the image is dropped onto the editor, but before the images_upload_handler fires?

Edit:

I tried a different approach of dynamically setting the images_upload_url in the init_instance_callback event as so:

```
images_upload_url: 'handler.php',
init_instance_callback : function(ed) {
    ed.settings.images_upload_url += '?foo=bar';
    console.log('changed images_upload_url to: ' + ed.settings.images_upload_url);
}
```

In that case the console.log actually outputs the changed 'handler.php?foo=bar', however it comes to actually uploading an image, it resorts back to the handler.php - seems it is not changed correctly?

Comment: how did you get drag and drop image uploading to work?  whenever i drop the image on the editor it wants to leave the page!

Comment: @Michael Use the paste plugin (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/) with paste_data_images: true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, you cannot modify the setting once the editor has initialized itself ... your attempt to use `init_instance_callback` is failing because once the editor is initialized you cannot change the value.

What I would do is try to inject the data you need to append as a JavaScript variable and then have the actual init object use that variable.  For example:

```
var urlParams = <?php echo $urlParamsAsAString ?> 
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  images_upload_url: 'handler.php' + urlParams,
  .
  .
  .
})
```

This example assumes that you are using PHP and have variable named $urlParamsAsAString that contains the string you need (e.g. `'?foo=bar'`).  You can certainly do the same with any server side language.

This allows each page load to determine what the right params are and as long as that variable is defined when you init TinyMCE they will get appended properly.

EDIT/NOTE:  If you are using a single page application where you don't load an init with each page reload, you will need to `remove()` and `init()` the editor each time you want to change the configuration details.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this approach however my app is a single page app. Each screen load/change is controlled by js, and the initial init is fired only once on the first php page load of the application (occurs only once). So when attempting this approach, it loads the variables correctly on the first load, but then with each javascript screen change, it doesn't get updated with the new dynamic variables that change on the js side. 

This was done for performance reasons so that the init doesnt need to be called with each page change.

Comment: In that case you would need to remove and re-init the editor each time you want this value to change.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but did end up going that way and reinitialising the editor with each page change and it seems to be working ok so far.

I've ticked the answer even though technically it was your follow up comment I went with. But your answer also helped by confirming that settings couldn't be changed after init, which stopped me bashing my head against the wall with that one. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I updated the reply with an edit to mention the remove / init cycle.  Glad you got this working!